# Generate a Match Schedule with Python 3

Tags: python

I'm struggling with generating a match schedule between teams.

The conditions are:

- 14 teams play 1 game per day (7 games per day) over 26 days.
- Every team play against each other twice. 1 home game and 1 away game.
- Every team play a Home game and an Away game every other day.
- A team can not play against itself. So each team got 13/14 opponents.

I've replaced my dates with day 1-26 as key, and my teams with ID's to illustrate simpler.

Example of  outcome:

```
[
    {1: [((7, 8), (6, 9), (5, 10), (4, 11), (3, 12), (2, 13), (1, 14)])]},
    {2: [((8, 1), (9, 7), (10, 6), (11, 5), (12, 4), (13, 3), (14, 2)])]},
    {3: [((9, 8), (8, 9), (7, 10), (6, 11), (5, 12), (4, 13), (3, 14)])]},
    ...
]
```

My current code looks like this:

```
from collections import deque, OrderedDict


teams_all = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
teams = teams_all[:int(len(teams_all)/2)]
matches = {}

for index, team in enumerate(teams):
    # Remove self to not match against self.
    opponents = list(teams_all)
    opponents.pop(index)

    # We reverse and rotate the opponents to give a 
    # different start opponent for each team.
    opponents = deque(opponents)
    opponents.reverse()
    opponents.rotate(-index)

    start_day = 1
    end_day = 26

    # We only loop 13 times instead of 26, because we schedule 
    # 2 matches at a time.
    for i in range(0, 13):
        opponent = opponents[i]

        # Init lists
        if matches.get(start_day, None) is None:
            matches[start_day] = []
        if matches.get(end_day, None) is None:
            matches[end_day] = []

        # We create both the home and away match at the same time
        # but with different dates, opposite side of the schedule.
        matches[start_day].insert(0, (team, opponent))
        matches[end_day].insert(0, (opponent, team))
        start_day += 2
        end_day -= 2

# Print to console to check result.
od = OrderedDict(sorted(matches.items()))
for key, match in od.items():
    print(key, match)
```

The code above generates the first line correct, but the next rows it always gets 1 duplicate (1 team play 2 matches in 1 day) and because of the duplicate, one team is missing completely.

I'm pretty sure my problem is with how I use `opponents.rotate()`. However I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simplified version:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

def make_day(num_teams, day):
    # using circle algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm
    assert not num_teams % 2, "Number of teams must be even!"
    # generate list of teams
    lst = list(range(1, num_teams + 1))
    # rotate
    day %= (num_teams - 1)  # clip to 0 .. num_teams - 2
    if day:                 # if day == 0, no rotation is needed (and using -0 as list index will cause problems)
        lst = lst[:1] + lst[-day:] + lst[1:-day]
    # pair off - zip the first half against the second half reversed
    half = num_teams // 2
    return list(zip(lst[:half], lst[half:][::-1]))

def make_schedule(num_teams):
    """
    Produce a double round-robin schedule
    """
    # number of teams must be even
    if num_teams % 2:
        num_teams += 1  # add a dummy team for padding

    # build first round-robin
    schedule = [make_day(num_teams, day) for day in range(num_teams - 1)]
    # generate second round-robin by swapping home,away teams
    swapped = [[(away, home) for home, away in day] for day in schedule]

    return schedule + swapped

def main():
    num_teams = int(input("How many teams? "))
    schedule = make_schedule(num_teams)
    pp(schedule)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
How many teams? 14
[[(1, 14), (2, 13), (3, 12), (4, 11), (5, 10), (6, 9), (7, 8)],
 [(1, 13), (14, 12), (2, 11), (3, 10), (4, 9), (5, 8), (6, 7)],
 [(1, 12), (13, 11), (14, 10), (2, 9), (3, 8), (4, 7), (5, 6)],
 [(1, 11), (12, 10), (13, 9), (14, 8), (2, 7), (3, 6), (4, 5)],
 [(1, 10), (11, 9), (12, 8), (13, 7), (14, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)],
 [(1, 9), (10, 8), (11, 7), (12, 6), (13, 5), (14, 4), (2, 3)],
 [(1, 8), (9, 7), (10, 6), (11, 5), (12, 4), (13, 3), (14, 2)],
 [(1, 7), (8, 6), (9, 5), (10, 4), (11, 3), (12, 2), (13, 14)],
 [(1, 6), (7, 5), (8, 4), (9, 3), (10, 2), (11, 14), (12, 13)],
 [(1, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 14), (10, 13), (11, 12)],
 [(1, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 14), (8, 13), (9, 12), (10, 11)],
 [(1, 3), (4, 2), (5, 14), (6, 13), (7, 12), (8, 11), (9, 10)],
 [(1, 2), (3, 14), (4, 13), (5, 12), (6, 11), (7, 10), (8, 9)],
 [(14, 1), (13, 2), (12, 3), (11, 4), (10, 5), (9, 6), (8, 7)],
 [(13, 1), (12, 14), (11, 2), (10, 3), (9, 4), (8, 5), (7, 6)],
 [(12, 1), (11, 13), (10, 14), (9, 2), (8, 3), (7, 4), (6, 5)],
 [(11, 1), (10, 12), (9, 13), (8, 14), (7, 2), (6, 3), (5, 4)],
 [(10, 1), (9, 11), (8, 12), (7, 13), (6, 14), (5, 2), (4, 3)],
 [(9, 1), (8, 10), (7, 11), (6, 12), (5, 13), (4, 14), (3, 2)],
 [(8, 1), (7, 9), (6, 10), (5, 11), (4, 12), (3, 13), (2, 14)],
 [(7, 1), (6, 8), (5, 9), (4, 10), (3, 11), (2, 12), (14, 13)],
 [(6, 1), (5, 7), (4, 8), (3, 9), (2, 10), (14, 11), (13, 12)],
 [(5, 1), (4, 6), (3, 7), (2, 8), (14, 9), (13, 10), (12, 11)],
 [(4, 1), (3, 5), (2, 6), (14, 7), (13, 8), (12, 9), (11, 10)],
 [(3, 1), (2, 4), (14, 5), (13, 6), (12, 7), (11, 8), (10, 9)],
 [(2, 1), (14, 3), (13, 4), (12, 5), (11, 6), (10, 7), (9, 8)]]
```

Comment: I'm very grateful for taking the time to write this long code example. However it's not correct, it's missing the requirement `Every team play a Home game and an Away game every other day.`. In this case teams play all their home games the first 13 days, and all their away games in the last 13 days. So Teams should alternate between Home and Away games every other day.

Comment: I completed the code based on your answer as you can see in my post. Thanks a lot of this thorough answer, it really helped me refactor my code and make sense of it. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Hugh's answer I was able to generate the complete code. It seems like it is almost always generating alternating Home and Away matches, there are a few exception and I believe this has to do with the rotation of the list - but in my use case almost perfect is pretty good as well.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

def make_day(teams, day):
    day %= (len(teams)-1)
    home_teams = list(teams)
    if day:
        home_teams = home_teams[:1] + home_teams[-day:] + home_teams[1:-day]

    half = len(teams)//2
    return list(zip(home_teams[:half], home_teams[half:][::-1]))

def make_schedule(teams):
    matches = {day: make_day(teams, day) for day in get_even_days()}
    swapped_matches = reschedule_reversed(matches, get_uneven_days())
    return {**matches, **swapped_matches}

def reschedule_reversed(matches, days):
    schedule = {}
    for day in days:
        schedule[day] = [(away, home) for home, away in matches[day+1]]

    return schedule

def get_even_days():
    start_day = 2
    days = [start_day+2*i for i in range(13)]
    return days

def get_uneven_days():
    start_day = 1
    days = [start_day+2*i for i in range(13)]
    return days

def main():
    teams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
    schedule = make_schedule(teams)
    pp(schedule)
    print(f"{len(schedule)} days")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite of Marcus's last complete code in Typescript.

```
import {zip} from "lodash";
const teams = [ "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",];

function getEvenDays() {
    let startDay = 2;
    let days: number[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        days[i] = startDay + 2 * i;
    }
    return days;
}

function getUnEvenDays() {
    let startDay = 1;
    let days: number[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        days[i] = startDay + 2 * i;
    }
    return days;
}

function makeDay(teams, day) {
    day %= teams.length - 1;
    let homeTeams = teams;
    if (day) {
        homeTeams = [
            ...homeTeams.slice(0, 1),
            ...homeTeams.slice(-day),
            ...homeTeams.slice(1, -day),
        ];
    }
    const half = teams.length / 2;
    return zip(homeTeams.slice(0, half), homeTeams.slice(half).reverse());
}

type Game = []
function rescheduleReversed(matches: {}, days: number[]) {
    let schedule = {}
    for(let day of days){
        const games: Game[][] = []
        matches[day + 1].forEach((match)=>{
            let game = [match[1], match[0]]
            games.push(game)
        })
        schedule[day] = games
    }
    return schedule
}

function makeSchedule(teams: string[]) {
    let matches = {};
    getEvenDays().forEach((day) => {
        matches[day] = makeDay(teams, day);
    });
    let swapMatches = rescheduleReversed(matches,getUnEvenDays())
    return {...matches, ...swapMatches}
}

const rounds = makeSchedule(teams)
for(let round in rounds){
    console.table(rounds[round])
}
```