# Football fixture algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I've been working on this algorithm for some time now (honestly a very long time), and I can't seem to see through what I'm missing.
The algorithm is an attempt to make all the possible fixtures in a 20-teams League (EPL) if all teams are to play each other home and away once a week. That'll make 10 matches a week if all teams play, 38 games per team (38 weeks) that's 380 games total.
The challenge is; that a team can't play twice in a match week (20 teams can only make 10 matches), and no same fixture is to be repeated.
The problem: In other to avoid any repetition, I check if the fixture and both teams have not been previously selected, But then the result shows 10 games each for the first 6 weeks, 8 for the next 9, 10 for the next 3, to 4 games for the last 2 weeks.
Please what am I missing here?

```
teams = ["ARS", "AVL", "BRE", "BOU", "BRI",
        "BUR", "CHE", "CRY", "FUL",
        "EVE", "LEE", "LEI", "LIV", "MCI", "MUN",
        "NEW", "TOT", "WHU", "WOL", "WAT"]

#All 380 possible fixtures len(fixtures) prints 380
fixtures =  [f"{home} - {away}" for home in teams for away in teams if home != away]

#38 match weeks if 10 matches are played everyweek. Each team plays only once per week
match_weeks = []

#Fixtures played // no same fixture is to be played twice
#i.e ARS - CHE can appear only once per seoson, but CHE - ARS only
s_fixtures = []

#Making fixtures for all 38 weeks
for i in range(38):
    match_week = [] #should be exactly 10 uniq games every week = 20/2
    s_teams = [] #teams already selected in the current week // 20 teams every week
    for fixture in fixtures:
        if len(match_week) == 10: #to save some iterations/time 
            break
        if fixture not in s_fixtures:
            home, away = fixture[:3], fixture[6:]
            if home not in s_teams and away not in s_teams:
                s_teams.extend([home, away]) # add teams to selected list
                print(len(s_teams))
                match_week.append(fixture)
                s_fixtures.append(fixture) #add fixture to selected list
    match_weeks.append(match_week)
```

Comment: The thing to do is get out a piece of paper and a pencil and solve the problem with 4 teams, and then 6. Once **you** know how to solve small versions of the problem, you can teach your computer how to solve larger versions. Alternatively, you may find that the problem cannot be solved in some cases.

Comment: @user3386109 have you ever encountered a  problem that cannot be solved?

Comment: You're not missing a thing here. That's exactly how it should work out. As the magnitude increases and as the weeks go on, there are less matches to choose from. You essential remove a team twice from the list of potential matches. Once a team hosts another team, that is removed from the master fixtures. Those 2 teams are then also removed from playing anyother games that week. Through that process, you are left fewer and fewer matchs that meet the criteria of a) can only host a given team 1 times, and b) can only play 1 game in a week.

Comment: So the assumption that there's 38 weeks of 10 matches is incorrect. You are correct that there are 380 fixtures.

Comment: @Jjenus Yes. Consider the following problem. There are 39 numbers, and you can buy tickets with 5 numbers per ticket. You want to buy every possible pair of numbers. There are 39 choose 2 possible pairs: 39C2 = 741. There are 5C2 = 10 pairs on each ticket. So you need to buy at least 74.1 tickets. You can't buy a fractional ticket, so round up to 75. Then the problem to solve is: generate a list of 75 tickets such that all 741 possible pairs appear at least once. That problem is not solvable. It is not possible to put all 741 pairs on only 75 tickets, even though there are 750 pairs.

Comment: It's easy to prove that it takes at least 78 tickets to cover all 741 pairs. But even then the question remains: is the problem solvable? Can you actually generate 78 tickets that have all 741 possible pairs?

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks for the input. After looking through the algorithm again, it only makes sense that there should be 38 sets of 10 matches but only 320 matches are selected leaving 60 more. I tried checking the half-filled arrays to accept more but it didn't work. Then I shuffled the fixtures and got from 361 to 368 in 10 tries, leaving from 19 to 12 more fixtures. How is that even possible?

Comment: I think I figured it out in my head. It's very particular as in which fixtures are scheduled for a week. It can;t be completely random, as to it needs to be able to fit each combination for minimum weeks. Give this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783767/generate-a-match-schedule-with-python-3) a look, and maybe can compare how he implemented it. This is an interesting one you posted btw

Answer (score 0):

Just showing my implementation and getting same as you. I'l continue to work on it and try to figure this out.

```
import random

teams = ["ARS", "AVL", "BRE", "BOU", "BRI",
        "BUR", "CHE", "CRY", "FUL",
        "EVE", "LEE", "LEI", "LIV", "MCI", "MUN",
        "NEW", "TOT", "WHU", "WOL", "WAT"]


fixtures =  [f"{home} - {away}" for home in teams for away in teams if home != away]
full_fixtures = list(fixtures)

finalSchedule = {}

week = 1
while len(fixtures) > 0:
    print(f'Week {week}')
    continueWeek = True
    matchCount=1
    week_fixtures = list(fixtures)
    while continueWeek == True:
        
        if week not in finalSchedule.keys():
            finalSchedule[week] = []
            
        
        #match = random.sample(week_fixtures, 1)[0]
        match = week_fixtures[0]
        
        finalSchedule[week].append(match)
        
        # Remove from fixtures
        fixtures.remove(match)
        week_fixtures.remove(match)
        
        # Remove those 2 teams from possible week
        team1, team2 = match.split(' - ')
        
        week_fixtures_removed = [x for x in week_fixtures if team1 in x or team2 in x]
        week_fixtures = [x for x in week_fixtures if team1 not in x and team2 not in x]
        print(f'\tMatch {matchCount}: {match} \n\t\t - CAN NOT SCHEDULE: {week_fixtures_removed}')
        
        matchCount += 1
        if len(week_fixtures) == 0:
            week += 1
            continueWeek = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. After looking through the algorithm again, it only makes sense that there should be 38 sets of 10 matches but only 320 matches are selected leaving 60 more. I tried checking the half-filled arrays to accept more but it didn't work. Then I shuffled the fixtures and got from 361 to 368 in 10 tries, leaving from 19 to 12 more fixtures. How is that even possible?

Comment: @Jjenus were you able to resolve this?I'm getting exactly what you've got. Looks like shuffling is the way forward.

Comment: Again, you have to be specific in what matches are chosen. It can't be random. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783767/generate-a-match-schedule-with-python-3)